# ListView getChildAt() stays null BUT if in onclick it works

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-listview

I have a ListView that is filled with items of an ArrayAdapter.
Now I want to strike them out when click and also check in the beginning if they are already struck through(calling an external api etc).
But it only works in the onItemClickListener the method above it doesn't.
to understand it better, here is some code:

```
public void machListe() { 
   listViewArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.task_item, ti);
   taskListe.setAdapter(listViewArrayAdapter);
   TextView ab=(TextView) taskListe.getChildAt(0);
```

So if I Debugg now I see that ab is null.

```
taskListe.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 

   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {

     TextView ab=(TextView) taskListe.getChildAt(0);
```

If I debug here, ab is NOT null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to saft the state of the tasks inside your Views.

You should try to separate Model and View at this point. 
Create a Model Object that contains a single task then extend [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) and overwrite [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29). In the getView you retrieve the correct task from the task list. Create the textview for the task and if the task is marked as done in your model you cancel out the text.

If you try to change the views in a list after they are created you would have to do this every time the list stops scrolling because the list will only hold childviews for the items that are shown on the screen, the other views are created during scrolling to save memory.

The only correct place to change a listview Item is in the getView method of the corresponding Adapter.

Have a look at the [ListsView Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) on vogella.de for more information.

Comment: works :-) but a bit not so fast, even with the "performance one"

Comment: Problem now is, that it updates the view every time an item becomes visible, but I'm loading the data from the server so it is not fluid!

Comment: haha silly mistake. I loaded it every time from the server to check if its done or not, but i save this in the array before, so this was useless and silly.... works fluetnly now :-)

Answer (score 2):

Setting the adapter will trigger a requestLayout but the actual layout is not done yet.
So taskListe won't have child-views yet when you call getChildAt(0) immediately after calling setAdapter

Comment: Can you explain why you need the child views at that point?  You can try to get the child view directly from the adapter (adapter.getView(0, null, ...)) but I'm not sure that will solve your needs.

Comment: of course: the method that contains this excerpt is called in the beginning of the onCreate, to get Task Items of an online to-Do Service. then it should strike-through all Tasks that are "done" and therefore I need the child views, cause each TextView is a Task.

Comment: Isn't it a better idea to subclass ArrayAdapter and override getView?. When the ListView calls getView (ie when the view will actually be shown) you can do the check whether the task is completed and ajsut the view accordingly.  Note also that taskListe (which is a ListView I assume) won't hold all views of your adapter but only those that are actually visible.  So iterating over all children of taskListe isn't equal to iterating over all your tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code and 2 is the index value

```
    View view=adapter.getView(2, null, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String value = textView.getText().toString();
```